# access returned result from a delete request mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m deleting an EnrichedEvent using its ID from enriched event collection. And also i need to update the same in project collection.I m able to achieve that, but once after 
deleting the enriched collection, when i tried to delete the same id again its showing Event removed only. When I delete the Event for the first time, it shows `{n:1, Ok:1}`, 
if i delete same Id for the next times,it shows `{n:0, Ok:1}` Which is right. but i want to know how to access these `{n:X,OK:X}`? So that i can write an If condition saying that 
`if Result== {n:1}` then event removed, otherwise event id doesnot exist. Or is there any other way to achieve this, Please Guide me in right direction.

Hers's my code.

```
router.delete("/:projectId/event/enriched/:enrichedEventId", (req, res, next) => { 
const enrichedEventId = req.params.enrichedEventId;
const projectId= req.params.projectId;
console.log(enrichedEventId);
console.log(projectId);
Project.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: projectId},
        { $pull: { enrichedEvents:  enrichedEventId} })
.exec()
.then(project =>{
if(project) {
    console.log("--------------");
    console.log(enrichedEventId);
  EnrichedEvent.remove({ _id: enrichedEventId })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        if (result== null) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              message: "ID not found"})
        }else{
                console.log(result);
                res.status(200).json({
                message: "event removed"});
            }
    })
} else if(project == null){
    res.status(400).json({
        message: "projectId is invalid"
    })}
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document found then you will get --> **`{ n: 1, ok: 1 }`**
and If it doesn't then you will get --> **`{ n: 0, ok: 1 }`** and then You can simply put the condition with `n === 0` or `n === 1`.

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: projectId },
  { $pull: { enrichedEvents:  enrichedEventId }}
).then(project => {
  if(project) {
    EnrichedEvent.remove({ _id: enrichedEventId }).then(result => {
      if (result.n === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "ID not found" })
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "event removed"})
      }
    })
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "projectId is invalid" })
  }
}).catch(err => {
  return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
})
```

Comment: its working fine... All this time i was trying (result===n:0). thank you so much... If its not a problem can you please upvote the question?.

Comment: Thank you so much... @anthonywinzlet  I hv been banned for last six months. I got an opportunity to question. So wanted to keep positive record.